# Python: Can a 3d plot made from a list of data points have a gradient color scheme?

Tags: python, colors, 3d, matplotlib

I have a list of points that are plotted in 3d, and I would like to have a gradient color scheme for the plot.  Is this possible?  If so, how can it be done?  I tried some of the examples on the matplotlib site but none of them worked.

Datagrid.txt is made up of 3 columns of numbers so `x,t,u` are 3 column vectors with the respected columns in the txt file.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import numpy as np
import pylab

x, t, u = np.loadtxt("datagrid.txt", unpack = True)

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')
ax.plot(x, t, u)
pylab.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ax.plot`, try [ax.plot_surface](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots).

**EDIT**

After discussions with the OP, we found out that the data was given in 1D column vectors, but `plot_surface` expects 2D arrays.  The data was grouped by `x` values, where each `x` value has 701 increasing values of `t`.  The data had to be reshaped into 2D arrays like so:

```
x = x.reshape((-1, 701))
t = t.reshape((-1, 701))
u = u.reshape((-1, 701))
```

Then, to get the gradient requires specifying a colormap:

```
ax.plot_surface(x, t, u, cmap=pylab.get_cmap('jet'))
```

Where the 'jet' colormap is requested.  A list of colormaps with matplotlib is available [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps).

Comment: the plot then comes up blank.

Comment: Are your input arrays each 1D or 2D?  If they are 1D, you will have to convert them to 2D.  Take a look at how they do it [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.py) (this is the source for the plot in the link I gave).

Comment: I suppose I should have asked, is this a surface or 3D line you need to plot?

Comment: it is a bunch of points that make up a surface. I will add an image of it.

Comment: I see.  Since it is a surface, at least the Z-axis data set is 2D, correct?  I can include in my answer how to convert 1D X and Y data points to 2D if you need.

Comment: Hmm... How can you plot a surface when `u` is just a column vector?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30288/discussion-between-sethmmorton-and-dustin)